# Как запустить linux с флешки с помощью Grub2?

Tags: linux, boot, root

Имеются компьютеры в аудитории, на которых запаролен bios.
Мне для моего исследования нужна java на этих пк, однако её нет.
Имеется linux на флешке с установленной java (записан с помощью UNetbootin)

linux: linuxmint-18.3-cinnamon-64bit
на целевом пк стоит загрузчик "grub2"

Я помню когда-то нам рассказывали что с него выбрать устройство и загрузиться с флешки, однако я забыл как.

1: Как определить каким устройством является флешка?
К примеру: root (hd0,5). hd0 - это наш хард, как будет выглядеть флешка?

2: Как определить chainloader?
chainloader /путь/имя_файла
Есть довольно подробная иструкция на хабре
https://geektimes.ru/post/99159/
Тут по инструкции я нашёл папку isolinux, однако нужного файла нету.

Собственно вопрос таков: Есть флешка с линуксом и Grub2. Как загрузиться?

Comment: Сколько компьютеров в аудитории?

Comment: если задача просто установить java на компьютер и grub не запоролен, то можно просто дописать `init=/bin/bash` в `cmdline`... в итоге при загрузке получить root оболочку (система не будет инициализирована), а после этого можно настроить, например, sudo на беспарольный вход или установить java...

Comment: *Как загрузиться?* - выбрать в меню загрузки ваше usb-устройство и загрузиться. если в bios это запрещено (и сбрасывать настройки тоже запрещено), то, насколько я понимаю, - никак.

Comment: alex, груб могёт)
roman > около 20 компов

Comment: Fat-Zer, можете рассказать об этом чуть подробнее? Груб не запаролен

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в принципе это не сложно, в самом примитивном варианте это просто вбить в консоль grub'а `set root=<устройство флешки>; chainloader +1; boot;`, но вот расписывать это всё в ответе с подводными камнями и скриншотами grub'а (из его консоли не так просто копировать текст) несколько накладно... ЗЫ: полезная ссылка [доки по командам grub2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну, если изложенное вами сработает в описанной ситуации, то для ответа, насколько я понимаю, не требуются "скриншоты и т.п.": найти нужное устройство (если это вообще "прокатит") можно командой [`search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#search). если соответствующий модуль доступен grub-у, конечно (обычно доступен).

Comment: @Fat-Zer [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, формально это был оффтоп к вопросу... предлагающий решение проблемы X, вместо Y, в таких случаях пакет ссылок с предложением найти детали в других источниках ИМХО вполне уместен... ну да ладно.... комментарий всё равно кому-то очень сильно не понравился...